# How do I make a table like this?

Tags: html, css, web-applications

http://weknowwhatyouredoing.com/

I'm trying to make a table like this one where I have a profile image to the left, a bold title/name and text underneath the bold title/name, and date/time stamp underneath that... basically the same views as on that website (http://weknowwhatyouredoing.com/) or better (or twitter tweets).

Anybody know of any tutorials on how accomplish this? I'm currently using table with multiple columns but it seems that when one cell is big, all the cells in that row become the same height and i don't like that. In android this is called a list view but i'm not sure what it is in the html/css world, any help please? Thanks in advance

Comment: debatable whether that's tabular data or not...I'd say not ;)

Comment: It could be expressed as tabular data, but in that case it isn't. Tables shouldn't be used there.

Answer (score 2):

You could make multiple tables floating next to each other. The elements on the website you show aren't aligned as fa as I can tell.

A tutorial on rowspan and colspan can be found [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html).

If you make the image span 3 rows, you can put the bold text, content and date stamp each into one row. With [valign](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp) you can vertically position elements within a row if the row becomes higher than the content. This will probably happen if the 3 rows together are higher than the one spanning row containing the image.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix for your issue with the equal row heights, you could use the same layout method as they use on [weknowwhatyouredoing.com](http://weknowwhatyouredoing.com/).

Wrap each column in a separate `<div>`, and then place your `<table>` inside.

4 containers, 4 tables with independent row heights.

Answer (score 0):

You shall give a look at the Twitter Bootstrap CSS library [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) 
It's pure HTML5/CSS  using only divs.

Answer (score 0):

for improve your knowleges in HTML, you can see W3C (Word Wibe Web Consortium) specs. For sample, if you see [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html), W3C explain all structure, attributes, for Table element.

You can find lot of tutorial in google  ( search "tutorial create Table HTML" ).

Also, you can help you to understand website structure with browser plugins that display hover element in specific website. ( [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox and Chrome, Dragonfly for Opera browser...)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use multiple list elements? Tables definitely don't give you flexibility for responsive designs. Making multiple columns of list elements can be rearranged as needed with limited restrictions